# firebase deploy Node "Warning: Accessing non-existent property"

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cli

When I run `firebase deploy` I get this Node warning:

```
(node:14802) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
```

I tried `firebase deploy --only hosting` and `firebase deploy --only functions` and got the same error message, so it's not my code.

I ran `node --trace-warnings ...` and got:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1083
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

That seems to say that the problem isn't in my code.

I tried Node v14.8.0 (the latest), v14.1.0, and v12.8.5.

Running `firebase tools --version` I get 6.3.1. The latest version is 8.7.0. I update all my npm packages at least one a week using `npm-check`. I ran `npm i firebase-tools` and its says that it installed 8.7.0 but when I run `firebase tools --version` I still see 6.3.1. I also ran `npm install -g firebase-tools`, again it stays on 6.3.1. How do I switch from 6.3.1 to 8.7.0?

`package.json` and `package-lock.json` say 8.7.0.

Comment: If you have information to add to your question, edit it using the "edit" link, and add the information to the question itself instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 12):

Fixed! The problem was that `firebase tools` was stuck on 6.3.1, despite having been updated regularly, with 8.7.0 installed. I ran

```
curl -sL firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash
```

and now `firebase tools --version` says 8.7.0.

`firebase deploy --only hosting` works but to get `firebase deploy --only functions` to work I had to go into the `functions` folder, open `package.json`, and change

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
```

to

```
"engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
```

I have no idea why regularly updating `firebase tools` didn't work.

Comment: This fixed it for me!